# Big Query API Exception

Tags: java, guava

I'm having this problem

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

while using Big Query API from Google.

I'm using JSF, GlassFish 4.1.

There is my method that is throwing the exception:

```
public void process() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
   GoogleCredentials credentials;
    File credentialsPath = new File("/home/jesus_miranda/Downloads/credential2.json");  // TODO: update to your key path.
    try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
    }
    // Instantiate a client.
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
    String query = "SELECT corpus FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` GROUP BY corpus;";
    QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();

    for (FieldValueList row : bigquery.query(queryConfig).iterateAll()) {//At this line the program failed.
        for (FieldValue val : row) {
            System.out.printf("%s,", val.toString());
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Please help me, I read a lot of forums and all of those talked about guava version. I update and downgrade the guava version and it still doesn't work.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

1. This problem seems to be the effect of a version mismatch. Take a look into the dependency declaration of the BigQuery API and see which Guava version is being used.
2. Maybe you are building your application and forgot to shade/fatjar guava into your jar.